# Publishing from SDL Web 8 content manager to 2013 SP1 content delivery server

Tags: 2013-sp1, web8, upgrade, 2013-sp1-hr1

I am planning to upgrade SDL Tridion 2013 SP1 content manager to SDL Web 8 but not the deployer and content delivery servers and I am planning to use the legacy publishing option to publish the items not the topology manager. We have applications in DD4T 1.0 and MVC 3.

Please let me know if anybody tried this and what are the configuration changes needed and also Is there any difficulty?

Comment: I would suggest try this and share your findings in the form of a blog :)

Answer (score 4):

I am currently supporting this mixed-mode scenario and it is working well; however, I am not supporting applications in DD4T 1.0 and MVC 3 and it is only an interim solution.

You will still need to [create topology manager](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v1/GUID-33187D11-0B59-4ABB-A67E-C448FD952F04) and [discovery service](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v1/GUID-12D1D919-2D08-40C3-91A0-B6C0A643C29F#addHistory=true&filename=GUID-CDFB3A61-BC24-4F6E-AB44-D3339D07F578.xml&docid=GUID-CDFB3A61-BC24-4F6E-AB44-D3339D07F578&inner_id=&tid=&query=&scope=&resource=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-CDFB3A61-BC24-4F6E-AB44-D3339D07F578) schemas (required for install/upgrade of SDL Tridion Web app). Obviously, you will not be able to leverage those until you update the Web 8 deployer jars files.

To enable the legacy publishing node [here](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v1/GUID-A3758A5B-8623-4EC5-BC46-459B2E91E39C#docid=GUID-3F49BCA1-4201-477E-928E-53E2E2143322&filename=GUID-3F49BCA1-4201-477E-928E-53E2E2143322.xml&query=&scope=&tid=&resource=&inner_id=&addHistory=true&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-3F49BCA1-4201-477E-928E-53E2E2143322) on CM side.

Here is a **great** step-by-step tutorial for [SDL Web 8 installation](https://pankajgaur83.wordpress.com/2016/01/10/installing-sdl-web-8-cm-and-db-setup/)

Comment: Andrew, Thanks for your reply.

You will still need to create topology manager and discovery manager schemas (required for install/upgrade of SDL Tridion Web app). What are the schemas? is there any reference for this?

Comment: I have updated my answer. I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, This is not mentioned in the upgrading SDL web in SDL Doc.